# How can I return a Pandas DataFrame, if the row is between certain weekday and time?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to make a trading bot, that will be only running during the CME Bitcoin futures open and close. Sunday through Friday, from 5 p.m. to 4 p.m. Central Time (CT). However, I want the bot running, starting from 5 p.m. Friday to 4 p.m. Sunday. I want the bot running at all time during that period, even outside 5 p.m. and 4 p.m. **ONLY IF** it is on Saturdays and Sundays. I hope that I've phrased it in an understandable manner.

My dataframe has a column called 'time' and is in unix timestamp. I've managed to convert it, but can't seem to find a way to return a dataframe that is between those period.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def is_cme_time(df):
    # convert unix time stamp to datetime
    df['time'] = df['time'].astype(int)
    df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x))

    # check if a time is during the cme bitcoin futures contract open and close
    cme_open = None
    cme_close = None


    return df[(df['time'] > cme_open) & (df['time'] < cme_close)]
```

Comment: for conversion to datetime, better use `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
# Initialize your min_time and max_time values
df[df['time'] > min_time and df['time'] < max_time]
```

Comment: can you please give more details in your answer?